# FBConnect login, share with a webview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FBConnect in my iOS project to authorize the user (SSO).

Once logged in, I sometimes need to open a Webview in order to show the user specific dialogs such as the app request dialog (invite to app) and even to open a friend's profile page in a webview for my app user to browse.

The problem is that the Webview doesn't recognize the logged in user and asks him to login again, this is not very friendly.

Any ideas how to share the logged in auth key/cookie/something with the webview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely running into this situation.  It's really frustrating.

[Facebook iOS SDK not storing cookies for access](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6964721/facebook-ios-sdk-not-storing-cookies-for-access/7124238#7124238)

You can, if you want, force the iOS library to use your app for login, and authorize through a UIWebview local to your app.  You are thus logged in, and have cookies to use.  You'll have to add a method to the existing Facebook object.  Normally, you call:

```
- (void) authorize:(NSArray *)permissions 
          delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```

to authorize, which in turns calls the private method:

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                    safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth
```

with both parameters set to YES.

You want to add a public method that calls the same private function but with both parameters set to NO.  I added this method to Facebook.m and declared it in Facebook.h so I could call it however I like:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions 
         tryFBApp:(BOOL) tryFBApp 
    trySafariAuth:(BOOL) trySafariAuth
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate {

    [_permissions release];
    _permissions = [permissions retain];

    _sessionDelegate = delegate;

    [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:tryFBApp safariAuth:trySafariAuth];
}
```

I call that with the two BOOL parameters set to NO, and the library pops ups a local UIWebView that leaves me with cookies that work for the app.

Comment: will that approach still gets me an auth key for my iOS app ? or only for the webviews ? and also, sounds like the webview will ask the user to login ? the whole point was to use the new facebook single sign on method to rely on the facebook app instead of asking the user to type username and password, will this support SSO ?

Comment: Yes, you'll get a valid auth token for making graph request.  You have to sign in somewhere, so yes, this will put up a login challenge when you call it, if the cookies are not valid anymore.  You can keep the auth token and cookie stored, and re use them - if you request offline access in your permissions, the cookies are good for a long while.  No, this will NOT be compatible with things that depend on SSO, like what FB calls deep linking.  You have to choose your poison.  There is no way to use the FB apps SSO as your aunt method and open a web view in your app without re-authenticating.

Comment: Just so its clear  - no, this is not SSO compatible - users will have to give you credentials at least once for your app. No way around it.  But I'd rather do this and get all my auth done in one chunk rather than create the expectation that SSO is available.

Answer (score 0):

FBConnect returns you a token so that you have access to the FB API not the FB website.  Unfortunately this doesn't login them in through a UIWebView and set the proper FB cookies.

Another strategy would be to change in the FBConnect source code to redirect to your own UIWebView instead of the standard FB pop-out to the FB-APP process and have them login only once.  You would however have to persist the cookie state of the UIWebView.

I suggest that you also take a look at http://www.getsocialize.com which can help you manage social network integration.

good luck!