# Facebook Comments Widget in iOS App with native authorization

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I'm trying to embed Facebook comments widget in iOS app, which already has Facebook authorization.

Can I use user's access token to set appropriate cookies into UIWebView?

```
- (void)loadComments {
    [_webView loadHTMLString:(@"<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
            "<html>\n"
            "<head>\n"
            "\t<title></title>\n"
            "</head>\n"
            "<body>\n"
            "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>\n"
            "<script>(function(d, s, id) {\n"
            "  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\n"
            "  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;\n"
            "  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;\n"
            "  js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en-US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=appId\";\n"
            "  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\n"
            "}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>\n"
            "<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"myUrl\" data-width=\"375\" data-numposts=\"20\"></div>\n"
            "</body>\n"
            "</html>") baseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:(@"https://myUrl")]];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //Maybe there is a better way to check auth redirect?
    if ([[request.URL absoluteString] containsString:(@"login")]) {
        [_webView loadHTMLString:(@"") baseURL:nil];
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[(@"public_profile")]
                                handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                     if (error) {

                                     } else if (result.isCancelled) {

                                     } else {
                                         //Here I need to set cookies, or something like that
                                         [self loadComments];
                                     }
                                 }];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I saw this question, but suggested answer will not work via native/facebook app auth: [FBConnect login, share with a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819876/fbconnect-login-share-with-a-webview/9831872#9831872)

I know, that I can use GraphAPI, but I don't want to implement whole comments logic and UI right now.

Answer (score 0):

Beside this You can use Social Framework of iOS SDk. It's very simple to implement.

But the user should have logged into fb in iOS Settings.

Comment: Is there any way to use Social Framework to retrieve and post Facebook comments?